# Можно ли создать массив функций?

Tags: c++, linux, массивы, функции

Программа ожидает ввода пользователя, и в зависимости от него выполняет разные функции. Код примерно такой:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void function1() {
    ...
}

void function2() {
    ...
}

int main() {
    string vvod;
    getline(cin, vvod);
    /* Далее обрабатываем ввод: в
    зависимости от ввода, выполняем
    разные функции */
    return 0;
}
```

В моём случае неприменим `switch-case`. Можно `if-else`, но, как по мне, громоздко *(да, бесят меня эти ваши `{}`, в том же **python** `if-else` куда грамотнее выполнен, да простят меня любители C++)*. У меня мысль такая: сделать два массива: массив строк и функций. Вначале ввод "прогонять" по массиву строк, затем получать порядковый номер, затем взять функцию из массива функций по порядку и выполнить именно её. С массивом строк проблем, мягко говоря, нету:

```
string vvod_variants[5] = { 'variant1', ... };
string functions[5] = { названия функций }
unsigned int a;
for (a=0; a<5; a++) {
    if (vvod==vvod_variants[a]) {
        break;
    }
}
// выполнить (functions[a])
```

А можно ли вообще сделать массив из функций и оттуда достать нужную? Сейчас изучаю указатели - в моём случае вроде бы с ними можно что-то придумать, только я не уверен... Подскажите, если в моём случае они действительно являются решением)

**ОС - Linux**

Comment: Раз уж С++ — сделайте `map`...

Comment: а потом узнаешь, что  питон switch-case подвезли только 2021 году https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60208/replacements-for-switch-statement-in-python ... хотя хотелось бы узнать, что такого в питоновском if-else есть, чего нет в обычном с/с++

Comment: конструкция if-else в python удобная, в отличие от C++. Если много ветвлений - будешь ломать себе голову скобками **}**.

Comment: ...а в Python'е — отступами.... (Чисто мое imho — это чего ж надо накуриться, чтобы отступы сделать частью языка?...)

Comment: @RandomDice779 Вы видимо как то не так пишите if-else в C. обратите внимание, что после слова else может быть либо одна инструкция без фигурных скобок, либо несколько инструкций в скобках. И так же обратите внимание, что сам по себе if со всем своим содержимым - это одна инструкция ! https://ideone.com/gjAV1h

Answer (score 4):

Вы хотите, как я понимаю, что-то вроде этого — пример для функций, принимающих и возвращающих `double`:

```
map<string, double(*)(double)> m =  {{"sin",sin},{"cos",cos},{"sqrt",sqrt}};

double x = 0;
string f = "cos";

cout << m[f](x) << endl;
```

Ну, разве что еще проверить, что такое имя и в самом деле есть...

Помочь с `if-else` в стиле Python не могу, в С++ никакие `if-else` для этого не нужны... :(